# Consuming handlebars.js template generated from ajax response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js, asp.net-ajax, jquery-select2

The [handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/) template is generated server side and returned as part of the response.

```
"<div>{{name}}<small style='color:#999;'><br><code>{{vafm}}</code></small><br><code>{{email}}</code></div>"
```

.

```
var t = "";

        $('#UniqueId').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: '/search/endpoint',
                dataType: 'json',
                processResults: function (data) {
                    t = data.template;
                    return {
                        results: data.results
                    };
                },
            },
            templateResult: Handlebars.compile(t),
            escapeMarkup: function (m) {
                return m;
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately the rendered part on [select2](https://select2.org/) does not contain the values returned by the `data.results`
[image]

I have located the issue to this line

```
templateResult: Handlebars.compile(t),
```

since trying something like

```
<script>
    const template = Handlebars.compile(@Html.Raw(Model.Template));
</script>
```

and

```
templateResult: template,
```

works as expected.

In the last example i pass the template from the model,

but not i need to pass it from the ajax response and achieve the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `templateResult` expects a callback function, but you are passing a compiled Handlebars template object. It's described here in [the select2 docs](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating). So, assuming that you already did the following in the right place:

```
var t = Handlebars.compile(...)
```

Then something like this would work:

```
templateResult: function(data) {
    if (!data.id) return data.text;
    return $(t({
        name: 'example name',
        vafm: 'example vafm',
        email: 'example email'
    }));
```

- The template html must have *one* enclosing element, so put things in a `<div></div>`, for example
- Your template is missing a `<small>` opening tag

---

So let's assume your server sends some JSON like the following. The template for every result is sent along and can be different for every result. Same goes for the template-specific data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Henry",
        "data": {
            "vafm": "1234",
            "email": "henry@example.com"
        },
        "template": "<div>{{text}}<br><small>vafm: {{data.vafm}}</small></div><small>email: {{data.email}}</small>"
    }, {
        "id": 30, 
        "text": "Tesla Roadster",
        "data": {
            "price": "$200.000",
            "color": "dark red"
        },  
        "template": "<div>{{text}}<br><small>price: {{data.price}}</small></div><small>color: {{data.color}}</small>"
    }
]
```

Together with something like this in your JavaScript, it should work:

```
$('#UniqueId').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '/search/endpoint',
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function(data) {
            /** Note: select2 expects "results" to be an array of objects, each containing
             *  at least "id" (becomes the value) and "text" (displayed text). I made the
             *  format from the server match that (plus added some more info), so that I don't
             *  need any conversions except for compiling the template. I do that with
             *  Array.prototype.map() in this case, but of course a for-loop would work too.
             */
            return {
                results: data.map(function(e) {
                    e["template"] = Handlebars.compile(e["template"]);
                    return e;
                })
            };
        }
    },
    templateResult: function(el) {
        if (!el.id) return el.text;
        /*  Note: "el" will be just like it came from the server, except for the
         *  modifications we applied in processResults. We can just pass "el" to
         *  the compiled template entirely and there, only pick what we need.
         */
        return $(el["template"](el));
    }
});
```

Comment: Your post was extremely helpful. Unfortunately i wish to create the template on server side since it will be based on endpoint. Hardcoding is out of context on what am i trying to accomblish

Comment: Okay sure, I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately this does not help either. The json properties and the template vary on endpoint. I am looking for a generic solution. I do not wish to stick on hardcoded properties such as email, vafm By using templateResult: template, i can achive that, but i wish to load the template from the ajax response, not from the model itself

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. The template itself can be different now, depending on the endpoint. Do you mean that the information that is filled in (name, email, vafm) should also be different, e.g. for a different endpoint it could be name, age, gender? If that's what you need, I could change my answer

Comment: Yes that is correct. For that reason i am generating both json and the corresponding template on the server. The end point could be anything, search/users, search/products and so on. This way i can get  for example userName, emailConfirmed, or in the second case productName, productPrice, or whatever suits my needs. I guess generating a keyvalue array from the data.results would do the trick

Comment: It seems this will solve my issue. Unfortunately i cannot test by tomorrow. What i do not quite understand is this workload. Why should i create the template for every record server side and not just map directly the template on the json results? it's a bit confusing to me

Comment: You could render the template in `processResults`, assign the result to `text`, and skip using `templateResult`. You'd also have to use `escapeMarkup` like you do in your question. The problem is that select2 would still display the full result DOM while the select is closed, overflowing the container. select2 has `templateSelection` and `templateResult` so that you can control separately how the currently selected item and the results in the dropdown are displayed, respectively. You could probably work around that by tweaking select2's styles, but I don't think that would be a clean solution.